# Value undefined

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

With my laravel project I'm trying to send an email with the following code:

```
    $mailTo = "theemail@hotmail.com";
    $mailToName = "hisname";

    Mail::send('emails.message.showmessage', array( 'name' => $mailToName), function($message)
    {
        $message->to($mailTo, $mailToName)->subject('New message');
    });
```

But I get the error:

```
Undefined variable: mailTo
```

How is this possible? I clearly set the variable with Undefined variable: mailTo, is it being unset in the Mail function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a local variable inside a closure (aka anonymous function) you need to use `use()`

```
Mail::send('emails.message.showmessage', array( 'name' => $mailToName), function($message) use ($mailTo, $mailToName)
{
    $message->to($mailTo, $mailToName)->subject('New message');
});
```

All variables specified in `use` will be available inside the closure all other won't.

Comment: Thanks never head of it, i thought because it was defined outside of the scope of the function it would be available.